# Rails controller using wrong method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controllers

I'm working on a Rails project that is giving me some problems. I've got a controller `characters_controller.rb` that has two methods.

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_player!

  def view
    @character = Character.find(params[:id])
    unless @character.player_id == current_player.id
      redirect_to :root
    end
  end

  def new
  end

end
```

I've got routes set up for each of those.

```
get 'characters/:id', to: 'characters#view'
get 'characters/new', to: 'characters#new'
```

The first route works fine. I can get go to /characters/1 and I'm shown the appropriate view and the requested information. If I visit /characters/new I'm shown an error that references characters#view.

```
raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{name} with '#{primary_key}'=#{id}"
```

and

```
app/controllers/characters_controller.rb:6:in `view'
```

So /characters/new is trying to get a Character from the database with an id of "new" but that doesn't work well. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Order matters in routes.rb, the router will find the first route that matches.

In your case, it would never go to `characters#new`, because the line above it will always match.

A simple solution would be to swap the two lines.

A better solution might be to use [resource routing as documented in the Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

Comment: That worked. I'll take a look at the link and see if I can improve my routes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rails parses routes sequentially and therefore it is considering 'new' as the `:id` for `characters/:id` route (which encountered first).

Just swap the order of routes  as follow:

```
get 'characters/new', to: 'characters#new'
get 'characters/:id', to: 'characters#view'
```

Answer (score 1):

If using this order in your routes.rb, for `/character/new` request, rails will understand that request is handled by `view` action with `paramas[:id] = 'new'`

Let `characters/new` before the other will resolve your problem:

```
get 'characters/new', to: 'characters#new'
get 'characters/:id', to: 'characters#view'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use resourceful routes, much cleaner:

`resources :characters, only: [:new, :show]`

Also I suggest rename `def view` to `def show` to follow rails convention

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
resources :characters, :path => "characters"
```

in your `routes.rb`